# How do I guard ubuntu for power outage?

Tags: filesystem, power-management, shutdown, embedded-system

I develop industrial equipment with embedded PC and Ubuntu 12.04.3.
Web server(apache) and DB(sqlite) running automatically when I turn on this PC.

User can't shutdown in the correct sequence. Because this PC has no display,keyboard,pointing device. User has to pull power line for shutdown. However,this process has the potential to crash Ubuntu.

I would like to build a system that will restart automatically after power outage. What could I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A) Buy a UPS.

B) You can shutdown properly over ssh.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

This embedded PC must be in small box.I can't use UPS.

I don't need power backup. But when power restart,the PC reboot quickly without any error or selection(e.g. fsck select).

Comment: You need a UPS, and you need to shutdown properly whenever you do need to shutdown. Otherwise you risk damaging components and the file system.